# Should we synonymize [diet] and [vegetarian-diet]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Yes, [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) is a bit more specific than [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet), but it's mostly identical.

Consider also that [vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism) was blacklisted, as 90% of the questions on this site are about vegetarianism, or at least can the questions can be applied to vegetarians.

[vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) has 5 questions tagged right now, and no wiki.

[diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) has 44 questions, and the wiki excerpt is:

> A particular/habitual eating pattern, for example, "I'm following a raw vegan diet".  This is a very general tag: please consider using more specific tags if possible.

What do you all think?  I'm personally in favor of synonymizing them, but I'd like more opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Half (22) of the questions tagged with [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) are also tagged with [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism). This seems to indicate a pattern of tagging diet related questions with both [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) and the relevant dietary restrictions.

2 of the 4 questions tagged with [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) mention dairy or eggs. Perhaps instead of creating a synonym, we should retag the questions as both [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) and [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto).

Comment: Yeah this. I think we should nuke the [vegetarian-diet] tag - it makes no sense as a synonym of [diet] because people are trying to use it to mean vegetarian-not-vegan. Synonymising it to [ovo-lacto] would make more sense!

Answer (score 0):

#### Keep [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) and burninate [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet)

It seems that the original usage of [diet] on this site was to pair it with other tags, so that questions would end up being tagged with `[vegan][diet]` or `[vegetarian][diet]` or similar. However, that goes against one of the first [directives about good tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) which is that tags should be able to stand alone on a question.

> Each tag should stand on its own: if a tag only makes sense when used in a group with other tags, something is wrong. For example, tagging a question as [visual] [studio] (two tags) is wrong.

I think we should aim to use tags that describe specific diet patterns wherever possible, and that's what I've written on [the tag wiki for [diet]](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/diet/info). The diet tag itself is just too ambiguous.

However, I have noticed there are quite a few questions that ask about vegetarian diet patterns without specifying a particular set of restrictions, and I think that [vegetarian-diet] works very well in those cases.